# How can I write a report (custom agenda view) of org-mode tasks and logbook notes that were recorded in a given time period?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use org-mode to manage my time whilst doing project work.

I break the task into TODO items and clock my work on them (`org-clock-in` and `org-clock-out`). Whilst I am working I use `org-add-note` to keep record of my thoughts and progress.

I want a report for any given time period (e.g. last day, week, fortnight, between x and y) to identify the tasks that I was working on at a given time and the notes (that are stored in LOGBOOK) which I wrote as I was working?

I've read through the org-mode documentation and can't see if this feature is already implemented somewhere, or if I should start from scratch, although I presume it is provided somehow by Custom Agenda Views. The closest I have seen to what I imagine is the Agenda Timeline View.

I will happily accept a link to documentation that leads me to write the correct code. Any working snippets are a definite bonus but the heart of my question is conceptual, how do I create a custom view or modify the existing Timeline View to do this?

EDIT: An example file and expected (hoped) output

```
* TODO Copy email from MongoDB to XML
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2015-06-01 Mon 08:40]--[2015-06-01 Mon 09:56] =>  1:16
  - Note taken on [2015-06-01 Mon 08:40] \\
    Ops gave me the address of a Mongo Instance, getting to work
  CLOCK: [2015-06-01 Mon 10:58]--[2015-06-01 Mon 11:00] =>  0:02
  - Note taken on [2015-06-01 Mon 10:59] \\
    Ooops! Ops gave me a live instance, I have asked they put Mongo into a vm bubble.
  CLOCK: [2015-06-01 Mon 11:49]--[2015-06-01 Mon 12:27] =>  0:38
  - Note taken on [2015-06-01 Mon 12:26] \\
    The instance of Mongod in the bubble has a licensing issue (lol, this is contrived).
  - Note taken on [2015-06-01 Mon 12:52] \\
    I've mailed Ops requesting he investigate the problem with logging into the bubble instance.
  CLOCK: [2015-06-01 Mon 14:31]--[2015-06-01 Mon 16:50] =>  2:19
  - Note taken on [2015-06-01 Mon 14:31] \\
    Adding checksum column to Contact Table
  - Note taken on [2015-06-01 Mon 15:42] \\
    Job done, emacs rocks!
  :END:
```

Output

```
2015-06-01 Mon 08:40 TODO Copy email from MongoDB to XML
2015-06-01 Mon 08:40 Ops gave me the address of a Mongo Instance, getting to work
2015-06-01 Mon 09:56 =>  1:16
...
2015-06-01 Mon 10:58 TODO Copy email from MongoDB to XML
2015-06-01 Mon 10:59 Ooops! Ops gave me a live instance, I have asked they put Mongo into a vm bubble.
2015-06-01 Mon 11:00 =>  0:02
...
2015-06-01 Mon 14:31 TODO Copy email from MongoDB to XML
2015-06-01 Mon 14:31 Adding checksum column to Contact Table
2015-06-01 Mon 15:42 Job done, emacs rocks!
2015-06-01 Mon 16:50 =>  2:19
```

This looks promising https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/677/listing-scheduled-headlines-from-an-org-file-ordered-by-date

Comment: I use entirely custom org-agenda views, but I don't use logbook or click-in/out, so it's a little difficult for me to conceptualize what it is that you want to do.  The three main functions that create the org agenda buffer are `org-search-view`, `org-tags-view`, and `org-agenda-list`.  All three gather the data and put them into a list called `rtnall` (which can be located via grep) -- the list will already have some text properties when it reaches that stage.  Here is a link to an example of data gathered by underlying functions:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287

Comment: @lawlist. That's doubley awesome. I had no idea of emacs.stackexchange. I've added an example org file and the fields i'd like to see in the output. If you can't answer the question, would you mind putting some example code somewhere or pointing me to your .emacs.d?

Comment: Emacs contains built-in support to search property drawers with `org-tags-view`:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  However, I didn't see anything built-in that can be used to generate a report similar to the call of the question.  I'll give it some thought, and perhaps in the meantime one of the local geniuses will post a solution and teach us all a thing or two. :)

Comment: You can almost do this with `org-agenda`'s log view (see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394394/orgmode-a-report-of-tasks-that-are-done-within-the-week).  It displays state changes and clock times, but not notes.

Comment: Hi @bluekeys, did you get a solution for this problem by any chance? I would like to solve the same issue that is I would like to be able to generate a report in emacs just like the one you described.