# How I can see tasks done on a particular day?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Org-mode agenda-view, how I can list tasks which are done on  a particular day?
I like to get view for a day or week  In the case of larger context of time, I like to have total number of task displayed.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this with custom commands -- e.g.,  `(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "\\* DONE\\|\\* NONE"))`  Here is a link to the manual:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html You will need to adjust the regexp to suit your needs -- e.g., it may have 1 star, it may have more than 1 star, it may have a different name other than done or none, etc.  The function `org-agenda-list` can focus on a particular day (i.e., the starting date with a span of 1 days)  or a span of many days.

Comment: See also:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Orgmode: A report of tasks that are done within the week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394394/orgmode-a-report-of-tasks-that-are-done-within-the-week)